# Social Login over API

Tags: php, api, laravel

Can't find a way to get over it:

I got my api ready lo log-in with google, this is my method in SocialLoginController

```
public function google(Request $request)
{
    // get data from request
    $code = $request->get('code');

    // get google service
    $googleService = \OAuth::consumer('Google');


    // check if code is valid

    // if code is provided get user data and sign in
    if ( ! is_null($code))
    {
        // This was a callback request from google, get the token
        $token = $googleService->requestAccessToken($code);

        // Send a request with it
        $result = json_decode($googleService->request('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo'), true);

        $user = $this->users->findByEmail($result['email']);

        if ($user == null)
        {
            $temp_pass = str_random(30);
            $data = [
                'name' => $result['name'],
                'email' => $result['email'],
                'password' => Hash::make($temp_pass),
                'google_id' => $result['id']
            ];
            $user = $this->users->create($data);

        }


        $payload = $user->permissions();

        if ( ! $token = JWTAuth::attempt($user, [], $payload)) {
            return $this->respondNotAllowed('User credentials are not valid');
        }

        $data = [
            'token' => $token,
            'user_id' => JWTAuth::toUser($token)->id
        ];

        return $this->respond($data);

    }
    // if not ask for permission first
    else
    {
        // get googleService authorization
        $url = $googleService->getAuthorizationUri();

        // return to google login url
        return redirect((string)$url);
    }
}
```

The things works, first time you hit the route, no 'code' attribute will be in the request and you end up making a redirect to google's authoritzation URI.
Then google comes back to you with the 'code' which you exchange for an access token and then I got access to the user profile.

This works, but now I can't get it to work on client application. I'm prrety sure that it doesn't work because when I make a AJAX call to my API the return ain't the expected, because what I get is the Redirect object.

This is my method on my client:

```
public function google()
{
    $result = Api::get('auth/social/google');



    if (isset($result['token'])){
        Session::set('access_token', $result['token']);
        $user = $result['user_id'];

        Auth::loginUsingId($user);
        return Redirect::route('home');
    }

    return Redirect::back()->with('errors', $result['error']);

}
```

Now, $result should contain a token I create but instead i have a redirect object. How can i solve this?